# How to convert multiple .jpg to .mp4 with individual duration for each .jpg?

Tags: python, image, video, jpeg, mp4

Let's assume I have multiple .jpg files in a directory and want to make an .mp4 file out of them - how can I do that but with an individual duration for each .jpg?

E.g. the first image should be shown for 3 seconds, the second one should be visible for 7 seconds, ...

Is it possible to achieve something like that with exisiting libraries?
Or should I just include the images multiple times into the directory, depending on their duration (which would end up making this inaccurate if I want an image to be shown less than a second)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to have a look at `mpv`, `ffmpeg` and `mplayer` (in that order). They might be offering you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using OpenCV

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

img_array = []
for filename in glob.glob('C:/New folder/Images/*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)


out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```

source: https://theailearner.com/2018/10/15/creating-video-from-images-using-opencv-python/